# Solving a parametric inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm trying to solve the following inquality:

$e^{5}-\varepsilon \leq e^x \leq e^5+\varepsilon$

Could you help me on how would I solve this equation? I am clueless how to start.

Thanks

Comment: What form of an answer do you want to achieve? Taking the log, you have $ln(e^5 - \epsilon) \leq x \leq ln(e^5 + \epsilon)$, and I don't see how this could be simplified further. If you are assuming $\epsilon$ is small, then you can have (approximating $f(x) = f(x_0 + \delta) \sim f(x_0) + \delta f'(x_0)$) then: $|e^{5 + \delta} - e^5| \sim e^5 \delta \leq \epsilon \Rightarrow \delta \leq e^{-5} \epsilon$.

Comment: @PedroFreire is there any way to investigate continuity without derivation in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By $x=5-\delta$ with $0<\delta<1$ we have that

$$e^x=e^{5-\delta}=e^5e^{-\delta}\ge e^5(1-\delta)=e^5-\delta e^5$$

then we can assume

$$e^5-\delta e^5\ge e^5-\epsilon \implies \delta\le\frac{\epsilon}{e^5}$$

then we have

$$e^x=e^{5+\delta}=e^5e^{\delta}\le e^5(1+\delta(e-1))=e^5+\delta e^5(e-1)$$

then we can assume

$$e^5+\delta e^5(e-1)\le e^5+\epsilon \implies \delta\le\frac{\epsilon}{e^5(e-1)}$$

therefore the inequality is satified for $$5-\frac{\epsilon}{e^5}\le x\le 5+\frac{\epsilon}{e^5(e-1)}$$

Comment: I'm lost right from the start. Could you please explain the first two steps? Thanks

Comment: @PeterF. I've used bounding values in order to find a range for x which satisfy the given inequality. In the first part, since $e^x\ge e^5-\delta e^5$ assuming  $e^5-\delta e^5\ge e^5-\epsilon$ guarantees that $e^x\ge e^5-\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you so much